# How can you make a change to the @Environment(\.calendar) in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, calendar, environment

I would like to change the `@Environment(\.calendar)` to use `calendar.firstWeekday = 2`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own instance of Calendar and then set it as the environment value

```
static let myCalendar: Calendar = {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.firstWeekday = 2
    return calendar
}()
```

And then when calling the view

```
SomeView()
   .environment(\.calendar, myCalendar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.calendar, {
                var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
                calendar.firstWeekday = 2
                return calendar
             }())
        }
    }
}
```

So all Views in the app get the same calendar.