# SwiftUI Change language in new Foundation Formatters iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, dateformatter

Hi everyone I keep having problems with the translation of the names of the months and days of my calendar ..

For `iOS 14` I'm using

`DateFormatter()`
(or `Calendar.current.shortMonthSymbols`)

for formatting the months of the calendar and for `iOS 15` I'm using the new formatting found in `Foundation`

```
Date().formatted(.dateTime.year().month())
```

In both cases I cannot translate the names of days and months from **English** to **Italian**

Some time ago I did not have these problems because the translation was done directly from the language of the user's real device instead now since I installed `iOS 15` on my real device the translations no longer occur automatically and I can't understand how I can solve it using a way elegant

Has anyone encountered these problems? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to set your calendar locale property:

```
var cal = Calendar.current
cal.locale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")
cal.shortMonthSymbols  // ["gen", "feb", "mar", "apr", "mag", "giu", "lug", "ago", "set", "
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion .. for using calendar i am using @Environment (\. calendar) var calendar

how can i optimize this?

Comment: @kAiN https://stackoverflow.com/a/65846026/2303865

Comment: I tried to create this and insert it in contentView but it still doesn't translate .. where am I wrong?
 `struct ContentView: View { var body: some View { Reservation() .environment(\.calendar, { var calendar = Calendar.current calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT") return calendar }()) } }`

Comment: show how you are using the custom calendar

Comment: for example when it recalls the months it does not translate `Text(currentDate.formatted(.dateTime.month()))`

Comment: solved in this way `@available(iOS 15, *)
    func formatMonthName(style: Date.FormatStyle.Symbol.Month) -> String {
        self.formatted(.dateTime.locale(Locale(identifier: "it")).month(style))
    }`